# Kali Linux зависает при запуске с флешки

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux

Запускаю линукс
     [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом доходит до этого момента и ничего не происходит. Если никак не манипулировать с ноутбуком(не нажимать тачпад или клавиатуру) , то появляется чёрный экран и все, никак не реагирует на нажатия
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно флешка сделана не правильно или образ поврежден. Сделай её через `dd` - наверняка будет

Comment: Да, использовал Rufus, записал как DD-образ

Comment: Тогда странно, а контрольную сумму проверял?

Comment: Sha256sum?      Вы про неё?

Comment: ну да, должна совпадать, если нет, дела плохи

Comment: Сигнал с Лиры Лебедя мне подсказывает, что видео не стартануло. Попробуйте failsafe

Comment: А sha1 и sha256 одно и тоже? Просто на kali.org sha256 , а мне выдает sha1

Comment: У меня та же проблема! Я не могу найти ответ